# How to automate click = "handleSubmit($event)" using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I tried all the above ways to click on the *Find It* button but i am not getting the response

- URL : https://www.jetblue.com/plan-a-trip/#/
- Button : Find it

Source Code

```
<input class="piejs" ng-hide="type=='bff'" value="Find it" ng- click="handleSubmit($event)" type="submit">
```

Can you please help in getting the result ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your Question:

Use one of the following options to click on "FIND IT" button:

1. xpath (with class attribute):

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='piejs']")).click();
   ```
2. xpath (with value attribute):

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Find it']")).click();
   ```

Let me know if this helps you.